# Upload video to YouTube using python getting this error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

> googleapiclient.errors.ResumableUploadError: <HttpError 403 when requesting None returned "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).". Details: "[{'message': 'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).', 'domain': 'youtube.quota', 'reason': 'quotaExceeded'}]">

Comment: "The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your quota."

Answer (score 1):

All Google apis have something called a quota. Your quota is used to limit the number of requests that your application can make either by user or the project itself.

By default when you create a project on Google developer console for the YouTube api you should either have a quota of 0 or a quota of 10k.  Once you have used all of your quota for the day you need to wait until the next day before you can make additional requests.

Uploading a video has a quota cost of 1600 points. This means with the default 10k quota you can upload about six videos a day.

- [Quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)
- [Intro to YouTube API and cost based quota for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MHUGuw1Agnc)